# Eclipse .metadata folder out of workspace

Tags: eclipse

The `.metadata` directory is in the directory of my workspace. Can I configure Eclipse so that the `.metadata` directory is not within the workspace?.

The reason is that we are many developers who use the same project directory and, if everyone starts its Eclipse instance on the same workspace, `.metadata` is modified by each developer.

Comment: Not an answer to the problem, but why not use 'proper' version control systems like SVN instead?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution. In my circumstances SVN is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot configure the path of the .metadata directory.

The way you are trying to use Eclipse is only going to lead to grief for you and your team. Each workspace keeps track of whether it has seen the current revision of the file. If multiple people are editing the same project files, everyone on the team will have to constantly invoke refresh. There is also risk of loosing changes as one team member can easily and silently overwrite changes made by another.

Try harder to use a source control system. Centralized systems like SVN that need to be hosted somewhere aren't the only option. Systems like git, allow you safely swap changes directly between team members.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I do not decide this way of working, coming on-imposed.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no way to have the `.metadata` directory outside of the workspace directory. However, you can have *your actual projects* outside of your workspace directory!

- For each developer, create a separate workspace, e.g. on that person's local hard drive. This workspace will hold that user's `.metadata` directory as well as *references* to the actual projects.
- Import the projects from the "shared workspace" (which now no longer is an Eclipse workspace but an ordinary shared directory) into the individual workspaces using *Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace*. Uncheck the *Copy Projects into Workspace* checkbox!

This way, each developer has his own workspace, with individual settings etc., while the projects still reside in a shared directory. However, this can lead to *serious* troubles, as Eclipse will be unaware of other people editing files in the projects. Thus, this should *only* be used as a workaround in case 'proper' version control systems like SVN or Git are *not* an option.

Comment: +1 because it's a good solution. But, I will wait for an answer that confirms whether there is a way to configure .metadata directory path.

Comment: I actually like this approach. While I do not wish to share my projects by folder sharing, with your approach, I can backup the projects to the cloud without backuping the huge (multi gigabyte) .metadata folder.